# How to represent fractions in python

Tags: python, matrix, fractions

I am trying to implement a method that takes a matrix from the matrix class i've defined and returns a triagonal matrix using gaussian elimination.
Consider the following matrix:

```
m1 = [[2, -3, -4],
      [-1, 4, 5],
      [1, -3, -4]]
```

Basically i need to add to each row, a multiple of another previous row, until i end up with a matrix which has 0 in all places below the main diagonal. Following this process, i should have the following matrix:

```
m2 = [[2, -3, -4],
      [0, 5/2, 3],
      [0, 0, -1/5]]
```

The problem is that fractions like 1/3 will often come up and i wouldn't want to lose precision by using floats. So is there any way to represent fractions? Will i have to define special behaviour for those? 
For the sake of doing it by myself i don't want to use any external modules.

Comment: `import fractions; print(fractions.Fraction(-1/5))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class that does exactly what you want: [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> print(Fraction(5, 6))
5/6
```

Fractions behave like regular numbers in most situations:

```
>>> print(Fraction(5, 6) + 6)
41/6
>>> print(Fraction(5, 6) + Fraction(1, 2))
4/3
>>> print(Fraction(5, 6) + 17.445)
18.278333333333332
```

The last example shows that the fraction gets converted to a `float` if the other operand is a `float`. This makes sense, since you would not expect a float of undetermined precision to be converted to a `Fraction`.

Comment: Am i able to perform operations on those just as i would with regular numbers?

Comment: @Alan. You should try it yourself, but I went ahead and updated the answer for completeness anyway.